# which one is better, hazelcast putAll vs set

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a map which has 25000 records. I tried to understand in hazelcast document for set vs putAll but I do not see any concrete answer on if which one is better.
Can I use directly putAll(map) ? And how storeAll helps along with putAll?
Is there any disadvantage of using that?

Also I see that put and set has hashcode implemented. Does putAll has also? Cause in document it does not mention about it.

Or should I iterate through map and set individual record in hazelcast map?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

@pratikgr,

- put & set operations are single key/value operations. Only difference is put returns old value & set doesnt.
- there is no setAll operation, since putAll also has no return. putAll accepts a map & do batch put, which is more performant than single put of course.
- When you call putAll, Hazelcast split the given map to pieces less then or equal to node count & send subMaps to each relevent member to store.

Comment: Thanks, and how about setAsync?

Comment: setAsync is also a single key/value operation. Only difference is caller get a Future immediately & no need to wait for operation complete.

Comment: Thank you. API says putALL is not guaranteed. is that true? And setAsync can be guaranteed?

Comment: What do you mean not guaranteed?